# initialState array wont show api info (Redux)

Tags: javascript, redux

I don't get why dispatch is not sendin list: [] the information, only info I got is list: [] has it's property in never[].

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";


export const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: "users",
    initialState: {
        list: [] /* (property) list: never[] */
    },
    reducers: {
        setUserList: (state, action) => {
            state.list = action.payload;
        }
    },
});

export const { setUserList } = userSlice.actions;

export default userSlice.reducer;

export const fetchAllUsers = () => (dispatch) => {
    axios
    .get('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2')
    .then((response) => {   
        dispatch(setUserList(response.data.data));
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error))
};
```

Comment: My question is why after you get the response you use this => dispatch(setUserList(response.data.data));